# RestResource Annotation - UrlMapping is NOT allowed

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, apexrest, restresource

As per the Salesforce Article [Winter / Spring '18 Apex Compiler Changes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264742&language=en_US&type=1) it is mentioned that

- UrlMapping is NOT allowed for @HttpPost
- UrlMapping and URL strings are NOT allowed for @HttpGet

but there is not any Suggested fix for that

Do anybody have an idea regarding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`urlMapping` is meant to be used only on `@RestResource` (and is required). The notes specify that `@HttpPost`, for example, must *not* specify a `urlMapping`.

---

## Valid

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/someUrl/')
global class MappedClass {
  @HttpPost global static void doPost() {
  }
}
```

## Invalid (But Previously Compiled)

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/someUrl/')
global class MappedClass {
  @HttpPost(urlMapping='/someOtherUrl/')
  global static void doPost() {
  }
}
```